# Form submit results in source code being displayed plain instead of being interpreted

Tags: jsf, facelets

I am trying to create a login page which checks for username and password from database.
As soon as I click on the submit button, it shows the code of welcome.xhtml file instead of showing the welcome page. Can anyone please let me know how to resolve this issue.

After making changes to login.xhtml to use facelets, I still have the same issue.

login.xhtml:

```
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">  

    <h:body>

      <h:form>

          <p>
              <h:inputText
                  id="username"
                  title="Username"
                  value="#{userBean.username}">

              <h:inputText
                  id="password"
                  title="Password"
                  value="#{userBean.password}">
              </h:inputText>

              <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" action="#{userBean.validate}"/>
          </p>

      </h:form>
  </h:body>
```

managed bean :

```
@Stateless
public class userBean implements Serializable {

    private String username, password;
    private String response = "";
    private UserFacade userFacade;

    public userBean() {
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUserName(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String validate(){
      System.out.println("in bean");
        response = userFacade.validateUser(username, password);

      if (response.equals("MATCH"))          
          return "welcome.xhtml";
      else
          return "login.xhtml";

    }
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate the problem and post some of your code?

Comment: What code exactly are you seeing after submit? The JSF source code or the generated HTML source code? Please show request/response headers as well.

Comment: This is an issue with your server. Your server does not understand how to render the xhtml page. May be, it is treating the page as plain text page without executing the server side code at all.

Comment: Are you positive that you're using JSF/Facelets? You were talking about XHTML files in Java EE context, so Facelets was assumed. But that form isn't a legit JSF/Facelets form at all. Aren't you confusing JSF/Facelets with legacy JSP or so? That onclick makes at least absolutely no utter sense. Where excactly have you learnt developing it this way? Anyway, put your mouse above the `[jsf]` and `[facelets]` tags below the question until a black info box shows up and click therein the *info* link.

Comment: Thanks for the help, will go through more tutorial.. Looks like i have mixed JSP and JSF.

Comment: After changing the form to incorporate Facelets,i still have the same problem. I am seeing the JSF source code.Can anyone please let me know  if I am missing something? Edited the code to show the changed form.

Comment: @Shilpa can you post your managed bean code ?? ..

Comment: @Chaitanya10, added the managed bean code too..Looks like its not rendering the xhtml file, so wanted to know if I was missing something.

Comment: AFter reading the tag info pages, I have made changes to web.xml, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified the xhtml declarations and jsf declarations for tags on top of .xhtml page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:body>
   your code here....
</h:body>

</html>
```

in your web.xml have you specified following,

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

in your managed bean try specifying "faces/"

```
if (response.equals("MATCH"))          
      return "faces/welcome.xhtml";
  else
      return "login.xhtml";
```

in your .xhtml login file use form instead of `<h:form>`

```
<form>
</form>
```

try specifying navigation rules in faceConfig

```
<navigation-rule>
  <display-name>login.xhtml</display-name>
  <from-view-id>/faces/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
  <navigation-case>
   <from-action>#{userBean.validate}</from-action>
   <from-outcome>welcome.xhtml</from-outcome>
   <to-view-id>/faces/welcome.xhtml</to-view-id>
  </navigation-case>
 </navigation-rule>
```

some resources for your reference,
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14545_01/help/org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.doc.user/html/gettingstarted/tutorial/JSF%20Facelets%20Tools%20Tutorial.html

Comment: Ya, i have included both DEFAULT_SUFFIX and Faces Servlet. Have tried with <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern> and <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>. STill sme

Comment: Its not showing the input text fields:username and password, forget going to the managed bean. But still added as u suggested. Still sme :(

Comment: If i use <form> instead of <h:form>, its considered a JSP not JSF. I initially had <form> since it wasnt working, I found out i had messed up JSP AND JSF so changed from <form> to <h:form>

Comment: <form> tag is a html tag you can use it in jsp or jsf infact if you use <h:form> it finally renders a <form> tag and its not a jsp tag of anykind its a pure html tag

Comment: Added the navigation rules too, still the same. I am using Netbeans 5.5 Does the version of IDE matter?

Comment: it does not matter which IDE your using. Anyway are you using spring security for this login?

Comment: No, am not using Spring. If i click on view source on the browser, I can see the code. So it is seeing the page. Then how come it is not displaying the fields?